# How do I change a variable in each iteration in a list comprehension?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

So I wrote this function that takes a string and removes consecutive duplicate words.

```
def remove_consecutive_duplicates(s):
    previous_string = None
    li = []
    for i in s.split():
        if i != previous_string:
            li.append(i)
            previous_string = i
    return " ".join(li)
```

> **input:** `'alpha beta beta gamma gamma gamma delta alpha beta beta gamma gamma gamma delta'`

> **output:** `'alpha beta gamma delta alpha beta gamma delta'`

But my question is how do I add `previous_string = i` it in a list comprehension? Is this even possible?

Normally if there wasn't any `previous_string = i` then I'd probably do it like this:

```
def remove_consecutive_duplicates(s):
    previous_string = None
    return " ".join([i for i in s.split() if i != previous_string])
```

But I have no clue how or where do I add `previous_string = i` in this case.

Comment: Two methods to [Remove consecutive duplicates from list](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-remove-consecutive-duplicates-from-list/) i.e. 1) using groupby + list comprehension, 2) using zip + list comprehension

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since Python 3.8 you could use [assignment expression](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) `:=`

```
def remove_consecutive_duplicates(s):
    prev = None
    return " ".join([prev := i for i in s.split() if i != prev])
```

Comment: The only answer so far that *answers*.

Comment: Just the things I needed. Gotta upgrade from 3.7. Thanks Alex!

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

One-line solution: *this should work for `python 3.6+`*

```py
[x for x, y in zip(values, values[1:] + [None]) if x!=y]
```

### Example

```py
## Dummy data
s = 'alpha beta beta gamma gamma gamma delta alpha beta beta gamma gamma gamma delta'
# create a list
values = s.split()

## Get required output
[x for x, y in zip(values, values[1:] + [None]) if x!=y]
# ['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma', 'delta', 'alpha', 'beta', 'gamma', 'delta']
```

Comment: @Rick Try this. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: This worked in my version of Python. Amazing solution CypherX! Thank youuu!

Answer (score 0):

It might get a bit unreadable at some point but if you're sure you want to do it in a list comprehension:

```py
def remove_consecutive_duplicates(s):
    words = s.split()
    return " ".join([words[0]]+[words[i+1] for i in range(len(words)-1) if words[i+1] != words[i]])

test = remove_consecutive_duplicates('alpha beta beta gamma gamma gamma delta alpha beta beta gamma gamma gamma delta')
print(test)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use 'groupby' function from itertools together with list comprehension as follow:

```
from itertools import groupby  
def remove_consecutive_duplicates(s):
    return " ".join([word[0] for word in groupby(s.split(" "))])
```

Its readable enough.