# how can I write for loops in one line when they have multiple statements inside within my code

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I wanted to write some for loops in a compact manner, i.e in just one line. Here are my loops:

```
step_1_file = []
step_2_file = []
step_3_file = []
step_4_file = []

for line in input_file:
     if line.startswith(tuple(A_keywords)):
        step_1_file.append(line)
            
for line in step_1_file:
    regex = findall(r'^[^[.|,|-]+(?=[.|,])', line)
    for matching_line in regex:
        step_2_file.append(matching_line)

for line in step_2_file:
    for character in line:
        if character not in characters:
            line = line.replace(character, '')
    step_3_file.append(line)
    
for line in step_3_file:
    if ' ' not in line:
        step_4_file.append(line)
```

I have been able to compact the first and the last ones like this:

```
step_1_file = [line for line in input_file if line.startswith(tuple(A_keywords))]
step_4_file = [line for line in step_3_file if ' ' not in line]
```

However, when trying second and third, I always get syntax error. I guess the way must be similar to the previous ones, but having more statements makes me a bit confused on how to do it. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Well list-comprehensions will be equivalent for a run-time consumption factor to explicit loops.

The are used because they can be easier to read at times.

But, conversely if you have multiple loops and are doing some operations on top of it, list-comprehension will make it less readable.

having said that, you can use the below code for `step_2_file` (test it on your data first):

```
for line in step_1_file:
    regex = findall(r'^[^[.|,|-]+(?=[.|,])', line)
    for matching_line in regex:
        step_2_file.append(matching_line)
```

List_comp:

```
ste=_2_file = [matching_line for line in step_1_file for matching_line in findall(r'^[^[.|,|-]+(?=[.|,])', line)]
```

You won't be able to do the same for the list `step_3_file` as far as I know, because you're updating the iterator `line`, which can't be done in a list-comprehension see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64478125/how-do-i-change-a-variable-in-each-iteration-in-a-list-comprehension) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291997/how-can-i-do-assignments-in-a-list-comprehension)